# Textbox textchange didn't work in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have `TextBox` in my popup page, what i need to do, is to check if the `TextBox` in the popup contains text for example `TextBox.Text.Equals("Admin");`

here is the `TextBox` definition:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="35px" 
      ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"
      style="text-align: right; font-size: x-large" Width="200px">
</asp:TextBox>
```

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(TextBox1.Text.Equals("Admin"))
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(typeof(Page), "closePage", "window.onunload = CloseWindow();");
    }
}
```

the function of `TextBox1_TextChanged` didn't fetch when the text is changed.

what i need to do, is to close the window when some text is entered, can anyone help me and/or suggest any other solution to solve this problem ? I dont need to press any button to close the window

#### (the text will be entered to the textbox using card reader and because of that i need to close it without any button click)

thank you so much

Comment: Have you implemented the `TextBox1_TextChanged` method? If so can we see it?

Comment: Yes, for sure- it's updated

Answer (score 0):

I think the text changed event should be handled client side. The text is a very volatile value, imagine what would it mean to go to server side whenever you press a key. The performance would be very bad.

Comment: Yes i know it's bad and there is no direct way to implement this, because of that i need any workaround to do it,

Comment: Please describe your issue in depth so we can help you. Sounds like something is not ok

Comment: In high level, what i want is to run functionalliy when text entered to the textbox

Comment: Isn't enough for you if you handle the leave event in javascript then manually perform whatever post back you want?

Comment: The postback is i will write later in the code behind - just need to fetch cs function when any text entered to the textbox. I dont want to click enter or tab or any thing

Answer (score 0):

The TextChanged Event of textbox is fired only when you change the content of the textbox and move the cursor out of the control. If your text is entered to the textbox by card reader the cursor will remain inside the textbox. After entering the text try clicking outside the textbox or press Enter or Tab and check your TextChanged Event is fired or not. if the event fired, make sure that textbox text is not cleared in your Page_Load event. You know the use of IsPostBack.